# How to get count & other columns for the same table in same query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying the below MySql query -

```
SELECT count(*), bug_id, 
       bug_status, 
       resolution, 
       short_desc, 
       DATE_FORMAT(deadline, "%m/%d/%Y")AS deadline
FROM   bugs 
WHERE  ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
         AND deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
       ) 
        OR ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
             AND deadline BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND 
                                  CURDATE() )        
       ORDER BY deadline ASC
```

but it returns the result with only one column as opposed to all 96 entries..

[image]

What could be the better idea so that I get count first and then all the results ?

Comment: I don't see a `count()` in your query so don't understand how your query relates to the results you show.

Comment: Why do you need a count like 1, 2, 3 in the query? You get the data in the result set and it is trivial to add a row count in whatever display layer you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full count in each row it's a bit ugly in MySQL. You basically have two choices:

1. Do two separate queries and put the result back together in the calling code
2. Effectively do two separate queries in MySQL and put the result together in MySQL

Here's how to put them together in MySQL - note how your `WHERE` logic has to be repeated:

```
SELECT
  CountOnly.RowCount,
  bug_status,
  resolution,
  short_desc,
  DATE_FORMAT(deadline, '%m/%d/%Y') AS deadline
FROM bugs
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS RowCount
  FROM bugs
  WHERE 
   ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
     AND deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
   ) 
   OR ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
        AND deadline BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() )
) CountOnly ON 1 = 1
WHERE
 ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
   AND deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
 ) 
 OR ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
      AND deadline BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() )
```

Comment: Following error faced on running the above query -

`Query: SELECT CountOnly.RowCount, bug_status, resolution, short_desc, DATE_FORMAT(deadline, '%m/%d/%Y') AS deadline FROM bugs INNER JOI...

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'CountOnly.RowCount' in 'field list'`

Comment: Sorry about that - I left out the alias on the `SELECT COUNT(*)` when I retyped. I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks Ed, it worked fine this time, only problem now is that count is being repeated with every row of results.. Any way by which we could just make it display once?

Comment: Not really, and sorry; I thought you wanted it to repeat with each row. If you're querying through a middle tier (PHP, C#, etc.) you can just do the main query and then count the results in your code if that fits in with your logic, or you can send two queries at once - one for count and one for detail - and you'll get back a collection with the two results, which you can step through. I've done it plenty in C# and it works nicely. I know it's doable in most other languages too. If this is an option for you you can Google `php mysql multiple queries` or whatever the middle tier language is.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of `COUNT()` (or any other aggregating function) in your `SELECT` clause turns your query into an aggregate query. Without a `GROUP BY` clause an aggregate query necessarily must return only one row.

If you must return a `count` item in every row, you're going to have to get it in a joined single row subquery. Something like this would do the trick.

```
SELECT b.cnt, a.*
  FROM table a
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM table) b ON 1=1
```

But for the big query you have, you'll have to repeat it twice where I've mentioned `table`.